# The attribute undefined error on hadoop common project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I just imported the hadoop projects to eclipse according to the information given in http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment and eclipse show some error in hadoop-common project and all the errors are in the same file which is /hadoop-common/target/generated-sources/java/org/apache/hadoop/package-info.java

Here is the one the eclipse error message:

```
The attribute branch is undefined for the annotation type HadoopVersionAnnotation
```

All the other errors are actually same. For example, another error says "The attribute date" instead of "The attribute branch".

Lastly i want to give the source code of the package-info.java file:

```
/*
 * Generated by src/saveVersion.sh
 */
@HadoopVersionAnnotation(version="3.0.0-SNAPSHOT", revision="930c89b105e19f1f4db755c0071378c507386824", branch="trunk",
                         user="byildiz", date="Mon Jul 16 18:56:16 EEST 2012", url="git://kaptan/home/byildiz/Desktop/hadoop-common/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common",
                         srcChecksum="e54b3f6cb07ea1cd833d1ab0b947ac39")
package org.apache.hadoop;
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? I'm seeing this in 4.2 (20120614-1722).

Comment: I am using Version: 4.2.0 Build id: I20120608-1400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this must be an Eclipse bug. I changed one letter in HadoopVersionAnnotation.java (specifically, version -> versionx (save) -> version (save)) to trigger a recompile, and all of the compile errors went away.